# How to get the space available of web server in php?

Tags: php

I have a domain name like 'mydomain.com'. I want to check how much space available on server with this domain name with the help of php.
Like for our hard drive we `use disk_total_space("C:");`. Can anyone help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main function is used to get space available is same as above said.
you have to use `disk_free_space()`. but the different is to know the server path. And put it in braces.

Comment: On my ubuntu server disk_free_space is not showing exactly as df -H command.  Note: i have converted bytes to GB, huge difference in result.

Answer (score 16):

Depending on the structure of the file system you can use something like the following for Linux hosts:

```
$df = round(disk_free_space("/var/www") / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
print("Free space: $df GB");
```

Or in your case it sounds like you're running on Windows so:

```
$df = round(disk_free_space("C:") / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
print("Free space: $df GB");
```

Answer (score 3):

use php  [disk_free_space("/");](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)

it Returns available space on filesystem or disk partition

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `disk_free_space()` function as described on PHP.net.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php

Comment: I read out this, but this site told about the disk space on hard drive not for server

Comment: The server contains a hard drive ;-).

Comment: Since PHP is server-sided, it will execute the function on the hard drive of the server.

Comment: So what i do for get server sided hard drive

Comment: This function will be executed on the hard drive of the server. You will only have to specify the directory for which PHP will check for free space. Please have a look at the examples on the link which I posted.

Comment: @MichielPater but the whole hard drive will not be allocated to one domain, especially if its a shared hosting. I think he needs the space remaining for his domain